# Combine array along axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to do the following:

I have a (4,2)-shaped array:

```
a = np.array([[-1, 0],[1, 0],[0, -1], [0, 1]])
```

I have another (2, 2)-shaped array:

```
b = np.array([[10, 10], [5, 5]])
```

I'd like to add them along rows of b and concatenate, so that I end up with:

```
[[ 9, 10], 
 [11, 10],
 [10,  9],
 [10, 11],
 [4, 5],
 [6, 5],
 [5, 4],
 [5, 6]]
```

The first 4 elements are b[0]+a, and the last four are b[1]+a. How can i generalize that if b is (N, 2)-shaped, not using a for loop over its elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to get all the summations in a vectorized manner to have a 3D array, which could then be stacked into a 2D array with [`np.vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) for the desired output. Thus, the implementation would be something like this -

```
np.vstack((a + b[:,None,:]))
```

Sample run -

```
In [74]: a

Out[74]: 
array([[-1,  0],
       [ 1,  0],
       [ 0, -1],
       [ 0,  1]])

In [75]: b
Out[75]: 
array([[10, 10],
       [ 5,  5]])

In [76]: np.vstack((a + b[:,None,:]))
Out[76]: 
array([[ 9, 10],
       [11, 10],
       [10,  9],
       [10, 11],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  5],
       [ 5,  4],
       [ 5,  6]])
```

You can replace `np.dstack` with some reshaping and this might be a bit more efficient, like so -

```
(a + b[:,None,:]).reshape(-1,a.shape[1])
```

Comment: Exactly the kind of solution I desired. Thank you also for the references to broadcasting and vstack.